# The supremum of the function $f(x)=\frac{1-\cos Nx}{1-\cos x}$

Tags: real-analysis, trigonometry, supremum-and-infimum

I have the following function:

$f(x)=\dfrac{1-\cos Nx}{1-\cos x}$

Where N is integer.

I know the function has Sup when x goes to $2n\pi$  $n\in\mathbb{N}$. But is it possible to show this? Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

We have:

$$ f(x) = \left(\frac{\sin(Nx/2)}{\sin(x/2)}\right)^2 $$
so $x=0$ is a stationary point, a local maximum, for which $f(x)=N^2$.

Such a maximum is indeed a global maximum, since the only solutions of 
$$ \frac{\sin^2(Nz)}{\sin^2(z)}=N^2 $$
occur at $z\in\pi\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: why x=0 is a stationary point? Is the function well-defined at x=0?

Comment: @Yikai: it has a removable singularity ($z=0$ is a simple zero both for $\sin z$ and $\sin(Nz)$), so it is enough to remove it.

Comment: Thank you for your answers.